# Can itertools be used for an unspecified number of dimensions in this case?

Tags: python, python-itertools

This is my code, working with dim=3, but I would like it to work for any dimensionality without having to manually edit code.

I would like to be able to vary the dimensionality between 3 and 20 eventually without manually having to ad for-loops.
I was looking at itertools, but don't know how to select the correct values from the tuples created by `itertools.product()` to square and add up for my if statement.

```
arrayshape = (width * 2 + 1,) * dim
funcspace = np.zeros(shape=arrayshape, dtype='b')

x1 = list(range(-int(width), int(width + 1)))
x2 = x1
x3 = x1

for i in range(len(x1)):
    for j in range(len(x2)):
        for k in range(len(x3)):
            if round(np.sqrt(x1[i] ** 2 + x2[j] ** 2 + x3[k] ** 2)) in ranges:
                funcspace[i][j][k] = 1
```

Comment: what is `ranges`?

Comment: it is a tuple with the values of the function that i want to change to 1.
so with ranges=(4,5) it marks the shell of a sphere with radius 4 and 5 from the center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `product` on `enumerate` of your vectors, which will yield the value and the index:

```
for ((i,v1),(j,v2),(k,v3)) in itertools.product(enumerate(x1),enumerate(x2),enumerate(x3)):
    if round(np.sqrt(v1**2+v2**2+v3**2)) in ranges:
            funcspace[i][j][k]=1
```

as a bonus, you get rid of the unpythonic `range(len())` construct.

I've cooked a more general case when you have a vector of vectors. It's a little harder to read because unpacking isn't done in the `for` loop.

The square sum is done using `sum` on the 1 indexes (the values), and if the condition matches, we loop until we find the "deeper" list to set the value to `1`.

```
for t in itertools.product(*(enumerate(x) for x in x_list)):
    # compute the squared sum of values
    sqsum = sum(v[1]**2 for v in t)
    if round(sqsum) in ranges:
        # traverse the dimensions except the last one
        deeper_list = funcspace
        for i in range(len(t)-1):
            deeper_list = deeper_list[t[i][0]]
        # set the flag using the last dimension list
        deeper_list[t[-1][0]] = 1
```

as noted in comments, since `x1` seems to be repeated you can replace the first statement by:

```
for t in itertools.product(enumerate(x1), repeat=dim):
```

Another comments states that since `funcspace` is a numpy `ndarray`, we can simplify the "set to 1" loop by passing the list of indexes:

```
funcspace[[x[0] for x in t]] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that is elegent.
But how do I make this work for dimensions other than 3? so for 3 to 20 without manually editing the code everytime I want to change dimensions?
I would like it all to to be depended on a variable dim.

Comment: `itertools.product(enumerate(x1), repeat=dim)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga setting the third array is slightly trickier, though. And yes, I overlooked that `x1`  `x2` ... are the same vectors

Comment: I believe since `funcspace` is a `numpy.ndarray` you can just do `funcspace[t] = 1`

Comment: Not exactly `t` as it contains values as well, but indexes can be extracted with a comprehension. Thanks, that's cool